# Reviving a dead iPod Touch 8GB (2nd gen?)

Tags: ipod-touch

I have an iPod Touch 8GB (probably 2nd gen) that stopped working. By this I mean that it cannot be turned on, an doesn't show any sign of activity when connected to the PC, a docking station and other chargers. Of course iTunes does not recognize the device when plugged in to the PC. This happened, without prior signs of a coming malfunction, about 2 months after I bought it, **used**, during the last summer.

What are my options in trying to bring it back to life? At the moment, buying a new iPod Touch is not an option.

Comment: 2 months? If you haven't jailbroken it, send it back to Apple for repair. If you have jailbroken it, this is Apple's payback.

Comment: @Time Machine - thanks, but I am not the original owner. It was bought used. Also, I do believe it was jailbroken by the original owner.

Comment: Always reset a computer or other device if you have bought it from someone who used it. Laptops, desktops, TVs, clock radios, iPods, everything.

Comment: That's certainly a good advice, but does it have something to do with this unfortunate situation?

Comment: If it's not jailbroken currently (and if it's a brick Apple can't tell anyway) Apple will still fix it at the Apple Store if you can get to one close to you.

Answer (score 3):

Try leaving it connected to a PC or Mac for several hours. If the Battery is completely empty, it will take some time to turn on. Happens to my 8GB iPod (which is not used much anymore) every time I leave it disconnected for 2 weeks or more.

THe only other option I can think of is trying to use a tool called RecBoot to boot the iPod into recovery mode. I don't know if that works (never needed it) and where to download it, but it's the only other option that would come to my mind.

Comment: thank, we already tried leaving it connected overnight and the day after, to no avail. I am not familiar with RecBoot, but given the PC does not even recognize it as connected, I don't see how a remote software tool can help here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure its charged (try at least 3 combinations of computer->cables, or cable->chargers in case a charger or cable is broken) you should take it to your local Apple store. They will diagnose the problem and fix it if it's in warranty for free. Although you bought it last summer you say it is a Second gen, which means it's probably not in warranty. They will tell you all your options.

Comment: @SeniorShizzle - thanks for your answer. As I mentioned, I bought it used, so I am not the original owner. And yes, it is older than 1 year, so warranty is not valid either.

Comment: and yes, I tried a few combinations of computers, chargers, docks and cables - but nada!

Comment: The 8 GB could still have been 2G.

Comment: Also, and this might not work. You can try booting the device into recovery mode. Leave the ipod plugged into the wall for a couple hours on a charger you KNOW works. Plug the charger into the mac, then hold the HOME button (NOT the power button or any other buttons) and slide the charger into the iPhone while still keeping the home button pressed for at least one minute. If after that time it doesn't work, try again. If not still, Apple store.

Comment: @SeniorShizzle - OK, I'll try - but I assume this works for a Windows computer as well? If not, then I need to find a MAC first... (BTW, it's an iPod, not iPhone, but again, I assume the procedure should be the same?)

Comment: @ysap As long as you have iTunes running it should work the same. It should also work on an iPod and iPhone. It's funny because I actually switched to iPhone half way through the post ;)

Comment: @SeniorShizzle - OK, thanks. I'll try the procedure sometime in the next days and will post the results.

Comment: @SeniorShizzle - tried that out, but it seems to be a total brick 8-(. First, I connected the iPod to the USB for charging overnight. Then, I activated iTunes (not a Admin account, but a regular user account), then held the home button while plugging the cable, twice, but nothing happened. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I guess at this juncture the only option is to take the iPod touch to an Apple Store. I don't know if there's one near you, otherwise you can call Apple and they will tell you a price for repairs through the mail. Sorry and good luck!